# NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am unable to get a numerical solution to a system of two coupled second order differential equations using NDSolve. These coupled ODEs are for a physical phenomenon known as a looping pendulum, and I am a high school student trying to get a testable prediction using this theoretical model. Here is the code I've written, kindly tell me what I should do to fix the error.

```
ClearAll;
R = 0.06;
m1 = 0.02;
m2 = 0.2;
\[Mu] = 0.34;
g = 9.81;
sol = NDSolve[{0 == 
     2*l'[t]*T'[t] + l[t]*T''[t] + R*((T'[t])^2) - g*Sin[T[t]], 
    0 == l''[t] + R*T''[t] + g - 
      e^(\[Mu]*T[t])*(m1/m2)*((l[t]*((T[t])^2)) - 
         l''[t] - (R*T''[t]) - (g*Cos[T[t]])), l[0] == 0.491, 
    l'[0] == 0, T[0] == 1.57, T'[0] == 0}, {l, T}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Euler number shoul be `E` not `e`!

Comment: Please write the ODE's as separate lines so it is easier to read, and better not use l for variable as it looks like 1 which make it hard to read.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Blame it all to Wolfram Alpha, where it accepts `e` as `E` ;)

Comment: @PiyushK What is the physical meaning behind `T[t],l[t]`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will make these changes. @UlrichNeumann, T[t] is the angular displacement w.r.t. the horizontal plane, and l[t] is the length of the string.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Do I have to define T[t] as an angle, if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @PiyushK That isn't necessary, the values of `T[t]` follow in `rad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code evaluates after changig `e` to `E`, but Mathematica gives a warning message  `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.2758858132758587`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

```
R = 0.06;
m1 = 0.02;
m2 = 0.2;
\[Mu] = 0.34;
g = 9.81;
sol = NDSolve[{0 == 
      2*l'[t]*T'[t] + l[t]*T''[t] + R*((T'[t])^2) - g*Sin[T[t]], 
     0 == l''[t] + R*T''[t] + g - 
       E^(\[Mu]*T[t])*(m1/m2)*((l[t]*((T[t])^2)) - 
          l''[t] - (R*T''[t]) - (g*Cos[T[t]])), l[0] == 0.491, 
     l'[0] == 0, T[0] == 1.57, T'[0] == 0} // Rationalize, {l, T}, {t,
     0, 5} , 
   Method ->  
      "StiffnessSwitching"];

Plot[{l[t], T[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 0.27}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!